# Angularjs dependency injection uglify

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For a while I am using this approach to inject dependencies in my angulur apps.

```
angular.controller('ctrlName', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log) {

}]);
```

As you can see, we usually pass dependency twice,

- once in array
- second time in function argument

So, today I thought why we do this, so I google it and read some answers on StackOverflow about it, and most of them said that they do it to `uglify` the code.

I know we can do this, in above example

```
angular.controller('ctrlName', ['$scope', '$log', function(scopeAlias, logAlias) {

}]);
```

but I am not getting how this uglifies the code.
So, I would like to know,

- **How injecting dependencies in above fashion helps in uglifying the code?**
- **Why would I want to uglify my Angular code?**
- **Why this approach is preferred during production?**

Comment: Renaming a few function arguments isn't uglification.  Uglification is build process that compresses your script.  [Check this out](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS)

Comment: look at the minified code...the argument names are changed but they can't be arbitrary due to being used for injection

Comment: *"Why would I want to uglify my Angular code"* .. smaller file size. Look at size difference between `angular.js` and `angular.min.js`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 3 types of dependency annotation in angular JS, and the one you are using is known as `Inline Array Notation`(preferred way as described in angularJS documentation). The other two are `$inject Property Annotation` and `Implicit Annotation`.

Generally speaking, using Implicit Annotation is considered bad practice as it will break with any minification/obfuscation tools because of how they rename their parameters.

You may refer to this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) to learn more about angular dependency injection.

**Inline Array Annotation**

```
someModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'greeter', function($scope, greeter) {
  // ...
}]);
```

**$inject Property Annotation**

```
var MyController = function($scope, greeter) {
   // ...
}

MyController.$inject = ['$scope', 'greeter'];
someModule.controller('MyController', MyController);
```

**Implicit Annotation**

```
someModule.controller('MyController', function($scope, greeter) {
  // ...
});
```

To answer your first question, your code won’t break after uglifying with the use of either Inline Array Notation or $inject Property Notation.

For your second and third question, Uglification actually means to minify your code using UglifyJS. The benefits of minification is that it actually helps in reduce the file size and hence reduce the time needed to transfer file and bandwidth serve. And this actually helps in increasing use experience (less time to load webpage) and save cost (less bandwidth means less money to pay).

Comment: Is this the correct way to inject modules in to app module 
var app = angular.module('wealth-desk', ['ngRoute', 'angular.filter', 'ngAnimate', 'ngMessages',
    function (ngRoute, filter, ngAnimate, ngMessages) {

    }]);

Answer (score 2):

Basically when you minify your code variables, function arguments etc, get renamed to be much smaller, therefore this breaks depedency injection in angular as angular is not longer able to know what depencies you have injected into your module/controller/service functions etc.

When u specify it twice like you are above you are anotating the component. Thus this creates a sort of mapping when minified, so the component is still able to infer what you have injected.

See this link for a good explanation https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

You would want to minify your code to reduce its size and decrease the amount of time it takes to transfer on request over the wire as well as to be parsed In the browser. Thus in production this is a very good thing to do. However you wouldnt need to do this in development as it slows you down (minifying lots of code can take time) and it can hinder your ability to catch and view application errors.

Answer (score 1):

When you run your JavaScript through a tool that uglifies your code it will change your JavaScript variables to be shorter and unintelligible. However the uglification process does not modify string values. This fact is what allows the dependency injection to work even after uglification occurs.

After uglification your code might be:

```
angular.controller('ctrlName',['$scope','$log',function(a,b){}]);
```

If your app is not a production level app and you will not be uglifying it then it is possible to drop the strings altogether and angular's DI will inject the dependency based on the name alone.

This will also work if the code is never uglified:

```
angular.controller('ctrlName', function($scope, $log) {

});
```

Comment: and third scenario use `$inject`

Answer (score 1):

> How injecting dependencies in above fashion helps in uglifying the
>   code?

Realize that uglification = minification. One step in minifying code is to substitute one variable name for a 
smaller variable name.  Specifying service names for $inject makes the controller's argument names irrelevant such that minification doesn't break the code.

> Why would I want to uglify my Angular code?

Again, uglify = minify.  The primary reason is minified code has a smaller network footprint.

> Why this approach is preferred during production?

Again, smaller network footprint.  When combined with compression e.g. GZip, significant savings can be had.  Here's a good read by Scott Hanselman as to why [compression is a good thing](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceAndEaseOfMinifyingYourCSSAndJavaScriptAndOptimizingPNGsForYourBlogOrWebsite.aspx).